# asp.net mvc 5 DropDownListFor with empty first item is always Required

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a viewmodel class that contains the following:

```
public class PersonalDetailViewModel
{
    public int TitleOfCourtesyId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Title of Courtesy")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TitlesOfCourtesy { get; set; }

    public PersonalDetailViewModel(){

        using(var db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            TitlesOfCourtesy = db.TitleOfCourtesies.ToList().Select(i => 
                                                new SelectListItem
                                                {
                                                    Text = i.TitleOfCourtesyName,
                                                    Value = i.ID.ToString(),
                                                    Selected = i.ID == TitleOfCourtesyId
                                                });
        }            

    }
}
```

This works fine and loads all the values from the DB into the `TitlesOfCourtesy` object. Please note that neither `TitleOfCourtesyId` nor `TitlesOfCourtesy` is marked as `Required`.

My view has the following code to bind this list to a drop down list:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary()
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.TitlesOfCourtesy, new { @class = "control-label col-sm-4" })

    <div class="col-sm-4">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TitleOfCourtesyId, Model.TitlesOfCourtesy, "Select", new { @class = "form-control", autofocus = ""})
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">

    </div>
</div>
```

But on the `Submit` button, the client validation prompts me as `The TitleOfCourtesyId field is required.`. Why? I have not mentioned it as `Required` in my code. Am I missing something?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change it to `int?` , (since `int` has a default value as zero)

Comment: Yes.. this was the issue. Thanks